# Get current user inside customer user creation form while saving

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have a form derived from UserCreationForm. When I create a member as an admin, on behalf of the member, I want to access the current user (admin), check few conditions, modify the new user object and then save.  But self.request throws    object has no attribute 'request'
 exception.

Tried if    self.request.user.is_superuser:    inside    save    method of    MemberCreationForm(UserCreationForm):    CBV.

```
class MemberCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        record = super(MemberCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            record.website_role = 3
            record.is_staff=True
```

want to get the current user (logged in user) before saving so that I can modify the new object and save according to the logged in users role.

Comment: You have to pass the request object to the form class from view.

Comment: Your view will have the request object, best to put this logic there

Comment: thanks, it works. I have moved the code into the view (override save method)